# Custom validation rule with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting a custom validation rule setup with knockout.js for checking if a username already exists. From my understanding, if the return is true then there are no errors, otherwise an error is set.

[Here's](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation#custom-validation-rules) an example of custom validation

```
//val is the username in question and searchType is the type of search(username or email)
function checkValue(val, searchType){
  if(searchType == 'userName'){
    $.post("/users/check_if_exists",{ 'type':'username', 'value': val },function(data) {
        var info = JSON.parse(data);
        if(info.username_availability == "available"){
            return searchType;
                            //I know this is working because I've alerted the searchtype here and it displays properly
        }
        else{
            return "unavailable";
        }
    });
  }
} 

ko.validation.rules['checkIfExists'] = {
    validator: function (val, searchType) {
        return searchType == checkValue(val, searchType); //if the username is availble, the searchType is returned back so it would return searchType == searchType which should be true meaning there are no errors
    },
    message: 'This username is taken, please select another.'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

I've checked the network tab and the POST is returning the correct value. If the value is available, I return the searchType. That way, it compares searchType == searchType which should be true. However, that's not the case.

Is there any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

**update**

Here's what I have as of now

```
function checkValue(val, searchType, callback) {
     var callback = function(data) {
        return true;
    }
    $.post("/users/check_if_exists", { 'type':'username', 'value': val }, function(data) {
        info = JSON.parse(data);
        if(info.username_availability == "available"){
            callback(true);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }); 
}

ko.validation.rules['checkIfExists'] = {
    async: true,
    validator: function (val, searchType) {
        alert(checkValue(val, searchType));//returns undefined
        return checkValue(val, searchType);
    },
    message: 'This username is taken, please select another.'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ko.validation calls your validation function.
There are two types of validation functions with regards to the way they pass the success/failure state back to ko.validation: the straight-forward return true/false way, or the "async" way.

The async way exists only because $.ajax exists and it's basically just this: instead of returning a value (which is impossible, as you are using an $.ajax call) you have to somehow notify ko.validation after the ajax response gets back to the browser, right?

So the smart people who wrote this library call your validation function with an extra parameter, a function (callback), that you have to call when the response is available.

```
function checkValue(val, searchType, callback){
  if(searchType == 'userName'){
    $.post("/users/check_if_exists",{ 'type':'username', 'value': val },function(data) {
        var info = JSON.parse(data);
        if(info.username_availability == "available"){
            callback(true);
                            //I know this is working because I've alerted the searchtype here and it displays properly
        }
        else{
            callback(false);
        }
    });
  }
} 


ko.validation.rules['checkIfExists'] = {
    async: true,
    validator: checkValue,
    message: 'This username is taken, please select another.'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working! You cleared up a lot for me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me turn your code into something more readable:

```
function checkValue(val) {
    var callback = function(data) {
        return 'bar';
    }

    $.post('url', 'data', callback); 
}

var x = checkValue('foo');
```

You are expecting x to be set to 'bar' when that is not the case.
I replaced your anonymous function with "callback" so you better understand that returning something from it does not mean "checkValue" will return anything.
After that your next problem is the fact that AJAX calls are asynchronous.

A validator function accepts three parameters: the value, extra parameters and a callback function. The callback function parameter is designed to aid you in exactly this situation.

Inside the success callback for the $.post you just have to call that callback function for the validator function passing true/false as a parameter.

```
function checkValue(val, params, callback) {
    $.post('url', 'data', function(data) {
        if(data === 'bar') {
            callback(true);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: No, it is not, but there are other solutions. I've presented one above.

Comment: Also, forgot about this, in the validation rule definition (ko.validation.rules['checkIfExists'] = {...}) you'll have to add "async: true".

Comment: Thanks, making some progress! I made sure to add var callback = function(....) before the post, but I still can't seem to get it working. I tried to alert(checkValue(val, searchType)) but got undefined. Am I supposed to somehow set it equal to the callback?

Comment: What's not right? The expected result or the way I'm doing it? I updated my original post to show what I now have.

Comment: See my response bellow. Again, your "checkValue" does not return anything yet you are expecting it to do so. There is no such thing. AJAX means asynchronous, that means code does not stop executing until you get the server response, so you have no way of "returning" something in the same function. You would require some form of "sleep" functionality and JavaScript does not permit such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

checkValue as you have written it always returns undefined. Invoking "return" from inside of a callback function only sets the return value for that callback function (not the "outer function"). If the validator function expects a return value right away (as knockout appears to do) you won't be able get that data asynchronously.

Comment: So is there any way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?